# Submitting app to Apple App Store (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, store

I wrote my app and it compiles. I have successfully tested it on my iPhone and in the simulator. So now I want to submit it to App World. I downloaded the Distribution Certificate, and (when Xcode 4.2.1 was minimized) dragged the certificate onto the Xcode dock icon.

When I go to Product -> Archive, it says "Build Succeeded" and gives me the Organizer window. I click "Submit" and sign into iTunes Connect, select my application, but when I go to select the Identity it says "iPhone Distribution (does not match any valid identity/profile pairs)". I configured my app on iTunes Connect (it says "Waiting For Upload").

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You should create a distribution provisioning profile using the Provisioning Profile management site, which you can find at the Apple Development Program portal. After having created this profile, you should open it up with XCode, then open your project and open it's properties (where you set the Icon and stuff) and select the tab "Build Settings". Click "all" and "combined" and then search for Code Signing. Expand it and set your Code Signing Identity (and of course Release and Release => Any iOS SDK) to iPhone Distribution. If all goes good, you should compile the project without any warnings or errors.

Now try uploading your app again, as you have imported your Distribution profile, you should now successfully be able to upload it.